# "ORA-01950: no privileges on tablespace 'SYSTEM' " : What error is it?

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g-r2, permissions, tablespaces

Earlier I created a user :

```
SQL>create user suhail identified by password
SQL>User created.
SQL>Grant create session,create table to suhail;
SQL>Grant Succeeded.
```

but when I login as `suhail` and try to create a `table` I get an error saying *`ORA-01950: no privileges on tablespace 'SYSTEM'`* .  What error is it ? Why does it occur ?

---

```
SQL> connect suhail
Enter password:
Connected.
SQL> create table suhail_table(name char(10));
create table suhail_table(name char(10))
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01950: no privileges on tablespace 'SYSTEM'
```

*I am using Oracle Database 11g Express Edition Release 11.2.0.2.0*

Answer (score 25, accepted):

This error says that the user doesn't have quota on tablespace `SYSTEM` which is set as the default persistent tablespace. You can assign a user the quota like this:

```
sql> alter user scott quota 50m on system;
```

Here, `50m` means that the user quota on the `SYSTEM` tablespace is 50 mebibytes. You can also set the quota to `unlimited`.

However it is a bad practice to store user and application data in `SYSTEM` tablespace as it causes data fragmentation and thus degrades performance. So I would recommend you to create a new permanent tablespace:

```
sql> create smallfile tablespace users datafile '/u01/app/oracle/oradata/ORCL/users.dbf' size 10g;
```

And then set it as the default database permanent tablespace so that objects created by the users go into that default tablespace:

```
sql> alter database default tablespace users;
```

Comment: can you please explain the command `alter database default tablespace users`

Comment: On Oracle XE 11, the users tablespace already exists, so you only need to `alter database default tablespace users;` and `alter user scott quota 50m on system;`

Answer (score 2):

You have to create one new tablespace into the database because for the `SYSTEM` tablespace access, `SYSDBA` privileges are required.

So, create one new tablespace and assign it as the default tablespace to all users. When you create any user, by default it will give assign particular tablespace.

Answer (score 1):

This error comes, when your user does not have sufficient space in the pluggable database folder.
You need to increase it.
There are two ways to perform this activity.

1. `ALTER USER <username> QUOTA 100M ON <tablespace name>`
2. `GRANT UNLIMITED TABLESPACE TO <username>`

`<username>`: currently logged in user, from which you are performing the activity.
`<tablespace name>`: check it from your error logs, currently the tablespace name is SYSTEM.